# Is there a previous-directory variable?

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables

The environmental variable in `$PWD` has the current working directory. Is there a variable that contains the previous directory? If there is not, how might one be created?

I think this could be useful.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, there is. `man bash` will lead you to

```
   OLDPWD The previous working directory as set by the cd command.
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this.

Comment: This is going to be so useful. (`uncd` command, anyone?)

Comment: You can use `cd -` to go back to the previous directory.

Comment: Bash maintains a stack of all directories you have visited. You can use `pushd` and `popd` to manipulate this stack. See `man bash` for details.

Comment: @NZD unless I've somehow been very confused for a long time, the stack does not contain _all_ directories you've visited - only those you've specifically stored using `pushd`.

Comment: @DavidZ Yes, you are right - my wrong. You can display the stack by using built-in command `dirs`.

Comment: @NZD You're probably thinking of autopushd with zsh `setopt autopushd` and every cd pushes onto dirs.

It's annoying IMO, but I'm sure some find it useful.